# How do I get all build steps to execute in Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build a number of client libraries to my system, each one targeting a different language. My configuration consists of a number of distinct build steps, one for each language, building and/or testing the library.

Right now, a breaking change in the system will cause the *first* build step to fail, and no other build step ever gets run, which is very inconvenient. I need to run all build steps, so that I can see all resulting errors.

One alternative would be for a configuration to exist to tell jenkins not to abort latter build steps if earlier ones fail. I didn't find any such thing, but maybe there is.

Another alternative I thought of was to trigger each language as a separate build, but then I have to tie them all up for my post build steps, and I'm not sure how to do that.

And, of course, there might be something I'm missing.

Any of the above would solve my problem. So, what should I do, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The [Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) Plugin is what you are looking for. I use this plugin a lot. Take a look at their screenshots - You can specify three options on how to mark a Phase(a Phase can have multiple jobs) as successful

- when the Phase Job's build was successful
- even if the Phase Job's build was unstable
- **even when the Phase Job's build failed** - *this is what you need*

In your case, you can create a Multijob Job that has one phase for each 'client library'. And add your respective 'client library' jobs into their Phrases. So if you have 10 'client library' jobs then you will end up having 10 Phases (one for each) in this MutliJob. And don't forget to set the '**Mark phase as successful when phase jobs' statuses are**' as '**Complete (always continute)**'

I usually don't prefer using Downstream Jobs for this purpose, because, there is no nice UI in Jenkins to look at the whole build flow in a single page. Ofcourse there is this [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) that shows each and every build flow status. You may choose the right plugin based on your need.

Comment: But if they are marked by successful, doesn't that mean post-build actions will be executed and the build itself marked as successful?

Comment: No you are only marking the Phase as successful, your build will still be showing up as a failed build (red ball). And that particular phase will show up as successful(blue ball). So that way, you are asking your Multijob to continue executing the other Phases.

Comment: By the way, there _is_ a nice UI to look at a whole build flow -- the build pipeline plugin.

Comment: Ok, another question... I now see that it means having multiple jobs, and then integrating then into a "multijob" job. However, that means each is run in its own workspace, which doesn't serve my purposes. I can hardcode the workspace, but if multijob is run on one server and any of its children is run on another, it won't work. Have you dealt with such issues?

Comment: Hey Daniel - Firstly regret the delayed response. That totally makes sense. In my case I had a simple setup without any slaves and all of them were on the same machine

Answer (score 1):

To make this work in one job, I think you need to make the build steps to not fail (return non-zero exit code). Then you need a post-build step which analyzes test results and marks build failed or unstable, if needed.

You may need to write a wrapper script to do the build, such as simple .BAT or shell script, which has `exit 0` as last line, after running the build/test actions.

Example of a post-build action which does this kind of test result processing is *Publish JUnit test result report*.